# Using href Within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using AngularFire and Firebase to store objects which contain a `title` and a `url`. I call the object `list`. I want to:

1. `ng-repeat` through my array of objects.
2. Use the `list.url` to download the URL's contents. All of the URL's are links to either a `.js` or a `.css` file.
3. Apply the download link/function to a `button` that is nested inside an `input-group` (Bootstrap 3.3.6).
4. All of this to be done within a routed view (`ui-router`)

[What the buttons look like within the `input-group`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2B3E.png)

Here's my div. It's nested within a routed view. I am working on the first button within `input-group-btn`.

```
<div class="list-group">
<a class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="(id, link) in links | filter: search | orderBy: '-downloadCount' | limitTo: 5">
    <h4 class="align-left list-group-item-heading">{{ link.name }}</h4>
    <h4 class="align-right list-group-item-heading">{{ link.downloadCount }}</h4>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="list-group-item-text">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="{{ link.url }}" />
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                // *** IT'S THIS FIRST LINK THAT ISN'T WORKING ***
                <button class="btn btn-default" ng-href="{{link.url}}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="copyToClipboard(link)" tooltip-placement="bottom" uib-tooltip="Copy"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-copy"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</a>
</div>
```

When I use anchor tags instead of button tags, the `ng-repeat` goes crazy, the links get all kinds of messed up, formatting goes haywire, and there ends up being only one copy of the button that doesn't even work.

I'm not sure if I'm supposed to interpolate the link that `ng-href` is referring to, but I've tried it with and without and I still don't have anything.

Here's my JS to answer a comment.

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://myApp.firebaseio.com/links');

$scope.links = $firebaseArray(ref);

$scope.addLink = function () {
    $scope.links.$add({
        name: $scope.newLinkName,
        url: $scope.newLinkUrl,
        downloadCount: 1
    });
    $log.info($scope.newLinkName + ' added to database');
    $scope.newLinkName = '';
    $scope.newLinkUrl = '';
};

$scope.incrementDownloadCount = function (link) {
    link.downloadCount += 1;
    var tempCount = link.downloadCount;
    var currentRef = new Firebase('http://myApp.firebaseio.com/links/' + link.$id);
    // update the downloadCount
    currentRef.update({ downloadCount: tempCount });
    // update priority for sorting
    currentRef.setPriority(tempCount);
    $log.info(link.name + ' downloadCount changed to ' + link.downloadCount);
};

// Possibly relevant includes
ui.router
ui.bootstrap
firebase
```

Comment: What is the value of link.url?
Can you share your JS code also?

Comment: I never worked with firebase. Can you please show me the structure of your links object?
Do the following (instead of the ng-repeat):
`<div class="list-group">
<pre>{{links | json}}</pre>
</div>`

Comment: My link object is {name: 'someName', url: 'https://somewebsite.com/file.min.js', downloadCount: 15}